# Unity RegisterType() Error: there is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, covariance, contravariance

I have a interface:

```
    public interface IFileRetriever<THeader, TBody, TTailer>
        where THeader : IFileRow
        where TBody : IFileRow
        where TTailer : IFileRow {

        IRetrievedFile<THeader, TBody, TTailer> Retrieve(string fileName); 
}
```

And here is a sub class:

```
public class FileRetriever<THeader, TBody, TTailer> : IFileRetriever<THeader, TBody, TTailer>
    where THeader : IFileRow, new()
    where TBody : IFileRow, new()
    where TTailer : IFileRow, new()
{
    private readonly IRetrievedFile<THeader, TBody, TTailer> retrievedFile;

    public FileRetriever(IRetrievedFile<THeader, TBody, TTailer> retrievedFile)
    {
        this.retrievedFile = retrievedFile;
    }

    public IRetrievedFile<THeader, TBody, TTailer> Retrieve(string fileName)
    {
        //do some thing
       return null;
    }
}
```

When I try to Register it in Unity,

```
    container.RegisterType<IFileRetriever<IFileRow, IFileRow, IFileRow>, FileRetriever<ReturnCheckHeader, ReturnCheckBody, ReturnCheckTailer>>(
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IRetrievedFile<ReturnCheckHeader, ReturnCheckBody, ReturnCheckTailer>>()
        ));
```

ReturnCheckHeader,ReturnCheckBody,ReturnCheckTailer is a sub class of "IFileRow"

I get an error:

> The type 'FileRetriever' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the
>   generic type or method 'UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(IUnityContainer, params InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'FileRetriever' to 'IFileRetriever'.

Comment: You should read about [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in C# to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @dymanoid thank you my friend, your infomartion 's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

//ensure the repository is disposed after each request by using the lifetime manager
container.RegisterType<IFileRetriever, FileRetriever>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

I've never used a construct like yours before, but I don't think you need to declare all of the sub-parameters.